# Apply onkeyup and blur to textbox by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 10 textbox but i want to apply onkey and blur event on 5 elements.

```
for(var x=3;x<7;x++){
            document.getElementById("txt_"+x).onclick=function(){
            put_contents(document.getElementById("txt_"+x));
        };
            document.getElementById("txt_"+x).onkeyup = function(){
            validateHexa(document.getElementById("txt_"+x));
        }; 
            document.getElementById("txt_"+x).onblur = function(){
            restore_it(document.getElementById("txt_"+x));
        };
}
```

after doing this when i click on textbox it is not put_contents take "txt_7" as parameter always.   Please suggest the right way. javascript only

Answer (score 2):

You can "detach" the value of `x` by creating a(nother) closure inside the loop:

```
for (var x = 3; x < 7; x++) {
    (function(x) {
        document.getElementById("txt_" + x).onclick = function() {
            put_contents(document.getElementById("txt_" + x));
        };
        document.getElementById("txt_" + x).onkeyup = function() {
            validateHexa(document.getElementById("txt_" + x));
        };
        document.getElementById("txt_" + x).onblur = function() {
            restore_it(document.getElementById("txt_" + x));
        };
    })(x);
}
```

For more information, see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102)